# aspnet table row

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to add a table in aspx page and need to have access to the table cells in .cs file. Created AspNet:Table with some rows and cells but keep getting 'not a valid identifier' error and can't see why:

```
<asp:Table runat="server" ID="tblStatus" Width="920" CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="0">
    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell runat="server" ID="LM6-D7-L"></asp:TableCell>
```

At the table cell row, I get:

```
Build (web): 'LM6-D7-L' is not a valid identifier.
Build (web): Literal content ('</asp:TableCell>') is not allowed within a 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCellCollection'.
```

This happens for every row in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET doesn't accept an identifiers with dashes in. You have to change the dashes to underscores or something else:

```
 <asp:TableCell runat="server" ID="LM6_D7_L"></asp:TableCell>
```

Or:

```
 <asp:TableCell runat="server" ID="LM6D7L"></asp:TableCell>
```

Etc.

Comment: Yep. And almost any programing language I know of.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to identify the control based on values in database for easy matching. I changed it and it is fine.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET does not allow hyphens in server controls ID's.  It's perfectly valid for non-server controls (those that do not have runat="server" on them) but asp.net is more picky.